# How to assign enum variable to a numerical variable? Java

Tags: java, enums, int

In this poker game code, I am trying to create a `Card` class. But, I wanted to use `enum` type instead of using `constant`,  because I heard it's better. The only problem is I tried many times to assign the instance value for `suit` and the `faceValue` which they are `int` variables to the `enum` type variable, but it says incompatible types. What's wrong?

```
public class Card {

    final static int MAX_SUITS = 4;
    final static int MAX_FACE_VALUES = 13;

    private int suit;
    private int faceValue;

    enum Suit {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS}
    enum Face {ACE, JACK, QUEEN, KING}

    public Card(int suit, int faceValue) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        if (suit == 0) {
            return suit = Suit.HEARTS; break;
        else if (suit == 1)
            return suit = Suit.DIAMONDS; break;
        else if (suit == 2)
            return suit = Suit.SPADES; break;
        else if (suit == 3)
            return suit = Suit.CLUBS; break;
    }

    public int getFaceValue() {
        if (faceValue == 1)
            return faceValue = Face.ACE; break;
         else if (faceValue == 11)
            return faceValue = Face.JACK; break;
         else if (faceValue == 12)
            return faceValue = Face.QUEEN; break;
         else if (faceValue == 13)
            return faceValue = Face.KING; break;
    }

    public void setFaceValue(int faceValue) {
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (suit > MAX_SUITS || faceValue > MAX_FACE_VALUES)
            return "invalid entry";
        else if((suit < 0 || faceValue < 0))
            return "invalid entry";
        else
            return faceValue + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change your constructor from `public Card(int suit, int faceValue) {` to `public Card(Suit suit, Face faceValue) {`...

Comment: @assylias I said, assign it to a numerical variable not changing it type! I hope next time you take the effort to read the problem better, instead of racing answers and evaluation.

Comment: @askd I read your question. My point is: you should try to get rid of the ints altogether: the whole idea of using enums is that you don't need to use int constants any more. If you keep using ints then you are not using the full power of enums. The only scenario where you may need to convert between ints and enums is if you receive the ints from an external source, say a file of data for example. In that case there are patterns to map between enums and ints, for example by adding an int constructor to your enums.

Answer (score 3):

> How to assign enum variable to a numerical variable?

You can't. You'll have to refactor and change all your uses of `int` (when representing a suit) to `Suit`.

Answer (score 2):

I hesitated do write this answer, because **it defeats the whole purpose of enums, and it does not make sense** to create any form of "mapping" between `int` values and `enum` constants.

Just don't do it.

Do what others suggested: Replace your `int` values with the corresponding `enum` constants. Then you also won't need these ugly workarounds with `MAX_SUITS` etc.

One (comparatively) clean implementation of the `Card` class could look as follows:

```
public class Card {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Card c0 = new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Face.ACE);
        Card c1 = new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Face.QUEEN);
        System.out.println(c0);
        System.out.println(c1);
    }

    private final Suit suit;
    private final Face face;

    enum Suit {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS}
    enum Face {ACE, JACK, QUEEN, KING}

    public Card(Suit suit, Face face) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Face getFace() {
        return face;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getFace() + " of " + getSuit();
    }
}
```

---

However, to still answer the question: It is possible to establish a mapping between `int` and `enum` values, with the built-in methods. You can use the [Enum#ordinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) method to obtain an `int`, and the (implicit) `Enum#values` method to obtain an array of the constants that can be accessed using an `int` as the index.

So the **NOT recommended** way of implementing it could be this:

```
public class Card {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Card c0 = new Card(Suit.HEARTS.ordinal(), Face.ACE.ordinal());
        Card c1 = new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS.ordinal(), Face.QUEEN.ordinal());
        System.out.println(c0);
        System.out.println(c1);
    }

    final static int MAX_SUITS = 4;
    final static int MAX_FACE_VALUES = 13;

    private int suit;
    private int faceValue;

    enum Suit {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS}
    enum Face {ACE, JACK, QUEEN, KING}

    public Card(int suit, int faceValue) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public int getFaceValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public Suit getSuitEnum() {
        return Suit.values()[suit];
    }

    public Face getFaceValueEnum() {
        return Face.values()[faceValue];
    }

    public void setFaceValue(int faceValue) {
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (suit > MAX_SUITS || faceValue > MAX_FACE_VALUES)
            return "invalid entry";
        else if((suit < 0 || faceValue < 0))
            return "invalid entry";
        else
            return getFaceValueEnum() + " of " + getSuitEnum();
    }
}
```

> Edit: I guess the confusion comes from the fact that you wanted to store the "face value" as an enum as well, and there are only enum constants for *some* of the face values (while the others are simply `int`, from 2 to 10). To put it that way: Storing the face value as an enum is probably not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Another not recommended way to do what you want:
(I've just written this code ad-hoc and not run it, so apologies for any typo's):

```java
public enum Suit {

  HEARTS( 1 ),
  DIAMONDS( 2 ),
  SPADES( 3 ),
  CLUBS( 4 );

  private int id = -1;

  public Suit( int id ) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public static Suit parse( int suitId ) {
    for( Suit s : values() ) {
      if( s.getId() == suitId ) {
        return s;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}



public enum Face {

  ACE( 11 ),
  JACK( 12 ),
  QUEEN( 13 ),
  KING( 14 );

  private int val = -1;

  public Face( int val ) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  public int getVal() {
    return val;
  }

  public static Face parse( int faceVal ) {
    for( Face f : values() ) {
      if( f.getVal() == faceVal ) {
        return f;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}


public class Card {

    final static int MAX_SUITS = 4;
    final static int MAX_FACE_VALUES = 13;

    private Suit suit;
    private Face faceValue;

    public Card(int suit, int faceValue) {
        setSuit( suit );
        setFaceValue( faceValue );
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit.getId();
    }

    public int getFaceValue() {
        return face.getVal();
    }

    public void setFaceValue(int faceValue) {
        this.faceValue = Face.parse( faceValue );
    }

    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = Suit.parse( suit );
    }

    ...
}
```

but your basically using the enum as an integer store in this scenario. External actors on Card basically interact with it only in terms of integers, so using the enum is purely internal and a little pointless here.

One other point about your initial implementations of `getSuit()` and `getFaceValue()` - I think you probably meant to use a switch there (the `break`'s do not have a huge effect in those `if/else`'s):

```java
Suit returnVal;

switch( suit ) {
  case 0: returnVal = Suit.HEARTS; 
          break;
  case 1: returnVal = Suit.DIAMONDS; 
          break;
  case 2: returnVal = Suit.SPADES; 
          break;
  case 3: returnVal = Suit.CLUBS; 
          break;
  default: returnVal = null;
           break;
}

return returnVal;
```